# Как сделать оповещение о запуске бота в discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Как должен выглядеть код, чтобы бот при запуске писал в определенный канал "бот был только что запущен."

Comment: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#async-def-on_ready

Answer (score 0):

```html
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)  # замените ID канала на свой
    await channel.send('Бот был только что запущен.')
```